# why do pooler use tanh as a activation func in bert, rather than gelu?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

class BERTPooler(nn.Module):
def **init**(self, config):
super(BERTPooler, self).**init**()
self.dense = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, config.hidden_size)
self.activation = nn.Tanh()

```
def forward(self, hidden_states):
    # We "pool" the model by simply taking the hidden state corresponding
    # to the first token.
    first_token_tensor = hidden_states[:, 0]
    pooled_output = self.dense(first_token_tensor)
    pooled_output = self.activation(pooled_output)
    return pooled_output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the [original BERT paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805) answered it (kind of) in a [comment on GitHub](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/43#issuecomment-435980269).

> The tanh() thing was done early to try to make it more interpretable but it probably doesn't matter either way.

I agree it doesn't fully answer "whether" `tanh` is preferable, but from the looks of it, it'll probably work with any activation.